# Hide Bootstrap nav collapse on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

By selecting a category from the responsive menu (the template is just one page), I want to hide nav collapse automatically when clicking. Also stroll to use as navigation, since the template has only one page. I seek a solution that does not affect it, here is the HTML code of menu:

site demo is here: 
[www.malouinternational.com/index2.html](http://www.malouinternational.com/index2.html)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div  id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left ">
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-top" data-id="top">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="our-team">OUR TEAM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="jewellery">JEWELLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="trade">TRADE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="social-corporate">SOCIAL & CORPORATE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="press">PRESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left " style="color: #000; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 15px;">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/MalouInternational"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Malou_Int"><i class="fa fa-twitter  "></i></a>
                <a href="https://instagram.com/malouinternational/"><i class="fa fa-instagram  "></i></a>
                <a href="mailto:info@malouinternational.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope  "></i></a>
                <a href="katalog/index.html" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-text navbar-right " style="color: #000; ">
                <li style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 13px; display:inline;"><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">TR</a></li>
                <li style="margin-right:10px; font-size: 13px; display:inline;"><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">EN</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search right" style="position: absolute; right: 70px; top: 0">
                <form>
                    <input class="sb-search-input" type="search" name="search" id="search">
                    <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                    <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you load jQuery and Bootstrap is important. Make sure you specify the jQuery library *before* Bootstrap JavaScript.

Additionally you have several 404 errors due to files missing from the server, you should resolve that too.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have a look on everything and came back here if I have a question if its ok with you :) –

Comment: If you have another question, it's best to post a new question. That way, others can help if I'm not able and people who have similar issues can also beneift.